# Пробросить данные между несколькими модулями одного store. Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Есть приложение на Vue.js,у  него есть store, разделенный на модули. Как получить данные из одного модуля в другом? 
Для организации store использую vuex

Comment: Для сторе вы используете vuex?

Comment: @Andrey Popov да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во `vuex` модульность не влияет на доступ к данным из `store`. Главное, чтобы все ваши модули были подключены.

**Пример**

**index.js**

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    moduleOne, moduleTwo
  }
})
```

**moduleOne.js**

```
state: {
loading: 'null'
},
mutations: {
    setError (state, payload) {
      state.loading = payload
    }
  },
getters: {
    getError(state) {
       return state.loadings
    }
},
action: {
    changeError({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setLoading', payload)
    }
}
```

moduleTwo.js

```
state: {
  someObject: ''
  },

mutations: {
   setSomeObject(state, payload) { state.someObject = payload }
},

getters: {
   getSomeObject(state) { return state.someObject }
},

action: {
   fetchSomeObject({commit}, payload) {
   commit('setError', null)
   /** какие-то асинхронные операции */
   then(response => {
   commit('setSomeobject', response.data)
})
.catch(e=> {commit('SetError', e.message)}
)
```

Можно увидеть из этого простого примера, что данные из `moduleOne.js` доступны в `moduleTwo.js`